# This version of the Android Support plugin for IntelliJ IDEA (or Android Studio) cannot open this project, please retry with version 4.3 or newer

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

Estaba trabajando en otra PC con Android Studio canary y ahora he cambiado de PC y he descargado mi proyecto de github y he vuelto a instalar android studio canary, sin embargo obtengo este error: `This version of the Android Support plugin for IntelliJ IDEA (or Android Studio) cannot open this project, please retry with version 4.3 or newer.` al sincronizar el archivo gradle

Comment: Estas usando una versión "canary"?, te sugiero actualizar Android Studio

Comment: Android studio ya soporta las funcionalidades de la version canary? (utilizo jetpak compose en mi proyecto)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eso es porque abriste la carpeta "app" en vez de la del proyecto. Tu proyecto debería estar en una carpeta con el nombre de tu applicación y dentro de esa hay una carpeta llamada "app". La que debes abrir desde android studio es la de afuera, la que tiene el nombre de tu proyecto. Si abres esa y todavía aparece el mismo error es porque falta el archivo `build.gradle` en la raiz del proyecto. Eso significaría que no subiste el proyecto completo a github o que el archivo fue ignorado por alguna regla de tu archivo `.gitignore`

Comment: bueno ahora tengo otro error ```This version of the Android Support plugin for IntelliJ IDEA (or Android Studio) cannot open this project, please retry with version 4.3 or newer.```

Comment: en la barra de herramientas selecciona Help > Check for Updates. Después de eso debería aparecer un mensaje con un botón para actualizar

Comment: Gracias ya esta

Comment: mi respuesta era correcta? puedes aceptarla?

Comment: En parte, ya que al decirme que actualize me di cuenta que había instalado otra cosa de la versión canary